# Validation in ActiveInteraction not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, interaction

My code(for debug):

```
require 'active_interaction'

class Sleep < ActiveInteraction::Base

  validate :validate_u

  def execute
    puts 1
    1
  end

  private

  def validate_u
    false
  end
end

res = Sleep.run
res.result
res.valid?
res.errors.messages
```

My result:

- 2
- 1
- true
- {}

Why is it? I was hoping the result would be:

- nil
- false
- {there are message about faild becous invalid}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
class Sleep < ActiveInteraction::Base

  validate :validate_u

  def execute
    puts 1
    1
  end

  private

  def validate_u
    errors.add(:base, :invalid) unless 'your validation condition'
  end
end
```

see doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

record invalid when has errors in errors object